# Vim: centering text within selection

Tags: vim

Every so often, I find myself drawing simple ASCII diagrams in Vim:

```
        +-----------+
... --> | foo       | --> ...
        +-----------+
```

Most of the time there is spent ensuring text is centered:

```
        +-----------+
... --> |    foo    | --> ...
        +-----------+
```

Unfortunately, so far I have been unable to automate that process: I'd imagine selecting the box (i.e. "foo" plus leading/trailing whitespace) in visual mode, then entering a command to center that selection (Vim's built-in `:center` applies to the entire line, which doesn't help me.)

Does something like this exist already? If not, how would I go about creating a simple script for this particular operation?

Comment: I ever wrote a script, to block texts, it supports `c,r,l` alignment. you can check if it is helpful: https://github.com/sk1418/blockit

Comment: That looks very similar to what I'm after, but I struggled to make it work as expected in my preliminary testing: I selected "foo" (plus surrounding whitespace) and used `:'<,'>Block` - but that reformatted the entire line rather than just this one box.

Comment: the "blockit" won't do exactly what you want. It add the "box" too. but you can have a look how the alignment part was done.

Comment: I had looked at https://github.com/sk1418/blockit/blob/4b23354eec54fb18e4260c4714939628d1adf6ca/autoload/blockit.vim#L116 - but due to my lack of vimscript fu, I have yet to derive a functional solution for myself.

Comment: I added a modified function as answer, at least it works for your example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is an adjusted function, you could test with your needs.

Note

- that this only works for selection in single line.
- also the border chars (E.g. `|` in your example) should not be selected.
- it works only for visual-selection
- create v-mapping if it you like.
- if it doesn't work perfectly for your needs, pls modify the function.

  ```
  function! GetVisual()
      try
          let v_save = @v
          normal! gv"vy
          return @v
      finally
          let @v = v_save
      endtry
  endfunction

  fun! CenterMe()
      let v = GetVisual()
      "let l = getline('.')
      let lre = '^\zs\s*\ze\S'
      let rre = '\s*$'
      let sp= matchstr(v,lre)
      let sp .= matchstr(v,rre)
      let ln=len(sp)
      let v = substitute(v,lre,sp[:ln/2-1],'')
      let v = substitute(v,rre,sp[ln/2:],'')
      let ve_save = &virtualedit
      let v_save = @v
      let &virtualedit = 'all'
      call setreg('v', v,visualmode())
      normal! gvx"vP
      let @v = v_save
      let &virtualedit = ve_save
  endf
  ```

This works like:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I'd hoped for - now I just need to grok the code... Thanks very much!